# how to auto restart jenkins when its not responding

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

We are facing issue with Jenkins instance in production environment that when multiple jobs are qued and during long running jobs like code scanning, our jenkins instance is getting hanged and not responding
most of the time need to restart the jenkins manually. So as a workaround we are looking for below scenario.

- Get a way to automatically identify when the jenkins become not responding or hanged
- Get a way to automatically restart the jenkins instance when jenkins is not responding moretahn 30secs..
- the approach should not restart the jenkins instance until its not responding as mentioned and restart is required.
- Is there any way to have these steps available with our cloud service azuredevops, so that the pipeline can be triggered in such scenarios.

Hope this is a known issue for most of the experts here and looking for your guidance on how we can get rid of such issues.

Comment: Have you investigated WHY it's hanging? CPU overload? Memory? Resource contention?

Comment: I don't think any "expert" implemented a logic to restart Jenkins automatically when it doesn't respond. For me it sounds that you have to increase the amount of allocated resources. If you use a lot of parallel stages in your jobs, you may think how to reduce their number. You may for example use [locks](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/) to not allow start the stage to many time. There is also a possibility prevent multiple builds of the same workflow at the same time: `disableConcurrentBuilds` ([Jenkins Syntax Options](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options)).

Comment: yes understood that the actual issue with jenkins and we are working to identfy the root cause. Meanwhile we are looking for this as a workaround for our developers who can trigger the pipelines themself when the jenkis is not responding, without help of any other operation teams assistance